# Web scraping data in R when there are a lot of links

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape baseball data from baseball-reference (e.g., https://www.baseball-reference.com/teams/NYY/2017.shtml). I have a huge vector of URLS that I created using a for loop, since the links follow a specific pattern. However, I am having trouble running my code, probably because I have to make too many connections within R. There are over 17000 elements in my vector, and my code stops working once it gets to around 16000. Is there an easier and perhaps a more efficient way to replicate my code?

```
require(Lahman)
teams <- unique(Teams$franchID)
years <- 1871:2017

urls <- matrix(0, length(teams), length(years))
for(i in 1:length(teams)) {
  for(j in 1:length(years)) {
    urls[i, j] <- paste0("https://www.baseball-reference.com/teams/", 
teams[i], "/", years[j], ".shtml")
  }
}
url_vector <- as.vector(urls)

list_of_batting <- list()
list_of_pitching <- list()
for(i in 1:length(url_vector)) {
  url <- url_vector[i]

  res <- try(readLines(url), silent = TRUE)

  ## check if website exists
  if(inherits(res, "try-error")) {
    list_of_batting[[i]] <- NA
    list_of_pitching[[i]] <- NA
  }
  else {
    urltxt <- readLines(url)
    urltxt <- gsub("-->", "", gsub("<!--", "", urltxt))
    doc <- htmlParse(urltxt)
    tables_full <- readHTMLTable(doc)
    tmp1 <- tables_full$players_value_batting
    tmp2 <- tables_full$players_value_pitching
    list_of_batting[[i]] <- tmp1
    list_of_pitching[[i]] <- tmp2
  }
  print(i)
  closeAllConnections()
}
```

Comment: What is the error message when the code stops? Is it because there is a connection timeout? Do you run out of memory? By the way, curl library might be a better way to scrape data from the web.

Comment: Yup, something about all connections being used. But I am confused as to why it would work for over 16000 links but stop just when it's almost done. I thought the `closeAllConnections()` command would prevent that from happening.

Comment: You might try getURL from RCurl to download as raw data and then parse with the xml2 package (which you are doing already with htmlParse and readHTMLTable).

Comment: By the way in any connection problem (a timeout etc), the code will stop, if you don't download the data through a system call with the "system" function. Best way to tackle this problem is to wrap the part of the code that actually makes the HTTP connection inside a "try" statement.

Comment: Could you perhaps give some examples? When I looked at the source code, the HTML code was quite complicated (and nested), so I wasn't sure how to scrape the data in an easier way.